# Convergence and limit of $a_{n+1} < \frac{a_n+a_{n-1}}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence such that $\forall n: a_n \in (0,1)$ and $a_{n+1} < \frac{a_n+a_{n-1}}{2} (*)$.

(1) Is it true that $a_n$ converges?

(2) Find all possible limits of such sequences

**Attempt**

Let $k_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. Then $(*)$ becomes $k_{n+1} < 0.5 + 0.5\frac{1}{k_n}$. So if $a_n$ was much bigger than $a_{n-1}$, then $a_{n+1}$ is smaller than $a_n$. Need to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}k_n=1$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$. Got stuck

**Edit**

This question is a 100% duplicate of [Convergence of sequence with $a_{n+2} < \frac{a_n + a_{n+1}}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2799381/convergence-of-sequence-with-a-n2-fraca-n-a-n12?rq=1)

Another similar (but not exactly same) question is [If $2a_{n+2} \le a_{n+1}+a_n$, then $\lim \sup a_n \le \frac23 a_2 + \frac13 a_1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862616/if-2a-n2-le-a-n1a-n-then-lim-sup-a-n-le-frac23-a-2-frac13-a-1)

Comment: I'm pretty this is a duplicate of one that I and others solved. I'll look for it.

Comment: did that before posting but found nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

(1) Show that it is decreasing (for large $n$) and bounded.

(2) Is it obvious that every number from $[0,1)$ can be a limit?

Comment: Not exactly obvious. I'm trying to wrap my mind around it...

Comment: (1) Thanks for the hint. It worked

Comment: Let us start from, say, $a_1=1/2$, $a_2=1/4$. Let $g=\lim a_n$. If $g>0$, then starting from $ba_1$, $ba_2$, we can obtain all numbers $bg$ for $b>0$. Larger numbers you can obtain by adding to $a_1$, $a_2$ a suitable $c>0$.

Comment: what if $g = 0$?

Comment: @VictorRogulenko Constructing a sequence tending to 0 is easy. $a_n$  must be less than, say, $\min(1/2^n,(a_{n-2}+a_{n-1})/2)$.

Comment: what I'm trying to say is, how do we know there exist g>0?

Comment: Why is $(a_n)$ decreasing? Take $a_1 = 1/2$, $a_2 = 3/4$, $a_n = 1/2^n$ for $n \ge 3$.

Comment: @VictorRogulenko Let $a \in [0,1)$. Define $a_n = a + (1-a)/(n+1)$. Then your conditions are satisfied and $a_n \to a$.

Comment: That's it. I think you guys nailed it here